Why is console.clear not clearing the whole console but just half?
I'm not sure what the problem is but here is my code. When I run it, instead of clearing the console and then printing the next frame, it just prints the next frame :(
I tried changing to internal terminal but still no good:
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string createMap(string[] map, int pyPos, int pxPos){

            return map[0]+"\n"+map[1]+"\n"+map[2]+"\n"+map[3]+"\n"+map[4]+"\n"+map[5]+"\n"+map[6]+"\n"+map[7]+"\n"+map[8]+"\n"+map[9]+"\n"+map[10]+"\n"+map[11]+"\n"+map[12]+"\n"+map[13]+"\n"+map[14]+"\n"+map[15]+"\n"+map[16]+"\n"+map[17]+"\n"+map[18]+"\n"+map[19]+"\n"+map[20]+"\n"+map[21]+"\n"+map[22]+"\n"+map[23]+"\n"+map[24]+"\n"+map[25]+"\n"+map[26]+"\n"+map[27]+"\n"+map[28]+"\n"+map[29]+"     X: "+pxPos+"; Y: "+pyPos+"\n";
        }
   
        string[] RefreshMap(string [][] layerVar, int pyPos, int pxPos, string player)
        {
            string[] layers = new string[]{"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};
        
            layerVar[pyPos][pxPos] = player;   // integrate play into map
        
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                layers[i] = layerVar[i][0]+layerVar[i][1]+layerVar[i][2]+layerVar[i][3]+layerVar[i][4]+layerVar[i][5]+layerVar[i][6]+layerVar[i][7]+layerVar[i][8]+layerVar[i][9]+layerVar[i][10]+layerVar[i][11]+layerVar[i][12]+layerVar[i][13]+layerVar[i][14]+layerVar[i][15]+layerVar[i][16]+layerVar[i][17]+layerVar[i][18]+layerVar[i][19]+layerVar[i][20]+layerVar[i][21]+layerVar[i][22]+layerVar[i][23]+layerVar[i][24]+layerVar[i][25]+layerVar[i][26]+layerVar[i][27]+layerVar[i][28]+layerVar[i][29];
            }

            string [] temp = new string[] {
                layers[0], layers[1], layers[2],
                layers[3], layers[4], layers[5],
                layers[6], layers[7], layers[8],
                layers[9], layers[10], layers[11],
                layers[12], layers[13], layers[14],
                layers[15], layers[16], layers[17],
                layers[18], layers[19], layers[20],
                layers[21], layers[22], layers[23],
                layers[24], layers[25], layers[26],
                layers[27], layers[28], layers[29]
            };

            return temp;
        }

        string floor = "¯¯";
        string roof = "__";
        string wallR = "▐▌";
        string wallL = "▐▌";
        string player = "╞╡";
        int mapsizeX = 30;
        int mapsizeY = 30;
        int pyPos = 0;// work on player movement; done - no collision; done with collision?;
        int pxPos = 1;// work on gravity and collision
        bool holder = true;

        Console.Title = "PathToRedemption";// work on game line
        string[][] layers = new string[30][]{// work on increasing map size; 10 => 30;
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{wallL,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ",wallR},
        new string[30]{floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor,floor},
      };
      int[][] mapCollision = new int[30][]{// work on increasing map size; 10 => 30;
        new int[30]{1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        new int[30]{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      
      };

      //console.keyavalaibale(key.space) === keyboard replacement
      while(holder){
        while(Console.KeyAvailable==false){// game tick
          
          Console.Write(createMap(RefreshMap(layers, pyPos, pxPos, player),pyPos,pxPos));
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
          Console.Clear();
        }
        while(Console.KeyAvailable){// player tick
          var pInput = Console.ReadKey(true);
          if (pInput.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape){
            holder = false;
          }
          if (pInput.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow){
            pyPos++;
            if (pxPos>mapsizeY){
              pyPos--;
            }
            else if (mapCollision[pyPos][pxPos]!=0){
              pyPos--;
            }
          } 
          if (pInput.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow){
            pyPos--;
            if (pxPos<0){
              pyPos++;
            }
            else if (mapCollision[pyPos][pxPos]!=0){
              pyPos++;
            }
          } 
          if (pInput.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow){
            pxPos++;
            if (pxPos>mapsizeX){
              pxPos--;
            }
            else if (mapCollision[pyPos][pxPos]!=0){
              pxPos--;
            }
          } 
          if (pInput.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow){
            pxPos--;
            if (pxPos<0){
              pxPos++;
            }
            else if (mapCollision[pyPos][pxPos]!=0){
              pxPos++;
            }
          } 
        }

        
      }
      
      Console.Read(); 
    }
  }
}

It doesn't work at all and I don't how why.
Try it out

This is way too much code for a [mre]. Try to shorten it to the bare minimum to show your problem.

For an MRE, focus on your issue: write 30 lines to the console and clear them. If the problem is not in the game code, then leave that out

OT instead of mentioning each index explicitly, use for-loops to iterate over them. Then you can adjust the game size without changing code

Try code like this: string[][] layers = Enumerable.Range(0, 29).Select(x => Enumerable.Range(0, 28).Select(y => " ").Prepend(wallL).Append(wallR).ToArray()).Append(Enumerable.Repeat(floor, 30).ToArray()).ToArray();

Add the following System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} in Console.KeyAvailable == false"); inside code block  while(Console.KeyAvailable==false) { ...}. Then Debug => Start Debugging. You'll see that you have an infinite loop in this code block.

Unfortunately, it's unclear what the desired behavior is, but it seems that you may have gotten carried away with using while loops.
